# How can I call a package-private method in Activity from SurfaceView?

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, surfaceview, package-private

I have a non-static, package-private method in my Activity class that I would like to call inside a SurfaceView, for instance: surfaceChanged() or surfaceDestroyed().

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {

Camera mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
boolean hasFlash = false;
...
    void destroyCamera() {
    flashOff();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
}

void updateCamera() {
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
...
class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
...
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    destroyCamera();
}
...
```

Is there a better way to do this? I also have a toggleFlash() method in the same activity so I can toggle the flash from within the activity through key listeners.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking. You say `SurfaceView`, but there is no mention of one in your code. Please be more specific.

Comment: Added the SurfaceView class that I am trying to call a method in the activity from. Can a pass the activity as a parameter in an overloaded constructor? What I'm asking is what is the best way to call a method in an Activity class from a SurfaceView  class. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment - yes, you can pass the `Activity` into the constructor in place of the `context`:

```
SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);
```

Then, as long as you are sure the `context` is the `Activity`, you can cast it to an `Activity` to call the method:

```
//call inside the view
((MyActivity) getContext()).methodToCall();
```

Other options include providing a static reference to your `Activity`, or getting access to your activity statically, via a weak reference, such as:

```
public static WeakReference<MyActitivity> getActivity(){
    return new WeakReference<MyActivity>(self);// self is a static instance of MyActivity
}
```

You can get a static reference to your `Activity` by assigning it in `onCreate` or the default Constructor:

```
private static MyActivity self;

public MyActivity()
{
    super();
    self = this;
}
```